# Problem with loading content without refresh by .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

why after several times click on buttons, is hang website? i use of function .load() for loading content(html). i use of firebug for solution this problem but did not succeed.
my purpose is this buttons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElWXy.gif

you yourself can see my site : http://zigweb.ir/siran/

and can see this js code to address: `http://zigweb.ir/siran/files/js/admin.js`

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url+' .load', function(){
                $(this).hide().show();
                $.getScript("http://zigweb.ir/siran/files/js/admin.js"); 
            })
            //.hide().show("slow")
        });
    });
```

please tell me, what do i do?
With respect

Comment: uhm 'http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js' refferes to local server, not to a server in the Internet. This could be one reason for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, were edited now can check.

Comment: Another question: Is it true that only the three first buttons don't works? It is a small challenge to use your site as a non (native) speaker of Persish.^^

Comment: after three click on button, site the hang. The not catch your second part question. What's your solution?

Comment: I think, it would be better to use relative path to avoid issue like this.

Comment: Like what? Please tell me example

Comment: Sangol meant: Instead of '$.getScript("http://zigweb.ir/siran/files/js/admin.js");' use '$.getScript("/files/js/admin.js");'

Comment: I changed, but the main problem(after several times(three times) click on button, site the hang) still exists

Comment: What will happen if you don't include the script 'admin.js'? In my eyes you don't need the code twice in your site. I've got the theory that multiple include of this script are the reson for your trouble.

Comment: i test all way but did not succeed for once upload, You have suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of a [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Chrome Inspector says,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/test/1st.htm. Origin
>   http://zigweb.ir is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

To fix this, you should change the request URL from `http://localhost` to `http://zigweb.ir`.

Comment: You should change the URL in anchor tags' `href` attribute, too. And one more thing, you don't need to write selector like `#nav #settings`, it doesn't help to improve performance when the second one also indicates id. Just do it like `#settings`.

Comment: I mean, change this `<a href="http://localhost/test/test2.php" id="delete_icon"></a>` to `<a href="http://zigweb.ir/test/test2.php" id="delete_icon"></a>`. And other anchors in #icon div also should be changed.

Comment: i changed href, but nothing happened.i tell after several times click on button site hanged, please click several times(e.x: 3 times) on add button after it yourself see that site hang, What causes this?